# Can't run findAll query in YugabyteDB using java driver core

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

We are using YugabyteDB yugabyte-2.9.0 and java-driver-core `4.6.0-yb-6` version but are unable to run `findAll` query, getting below exception:

```java
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.EmptyColumnDefinitions.get(EmptyColumnDefinitions.java:41)
    at com.yugabyte.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.PartitionAwarePolicy.getQueryPlan(PartitionAwarePolicy.java:107)
    at com.yugabyte.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.PartitionAwarePolicy.newQueryPlan(PartitionAwarePolicy.java:75)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.newQueryPlan(LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.java:155)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:211)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.<init>(CqlRequestHandler.java:191)
ColumnDefinitions is not getting populated properly (edited)
```

Code:

```
 @Test
    public  void findAllAttributeTest(){
        List<MyClass> list = myClassRepository.findAll();
        Assert.assertNotNull(list);
    }
```

And table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE my_list.attribute (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    fields jsonb
) WITH transactions = {'enabled': 'true'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yugabyte/java-driver-core/4.6.0-yb-9?  should fix the behavior you're seeing.